# Can't convert my char input from another input file into char*

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

trying to display input to the screen. Then, convert that text from a downloaded file into pig latin using strings and functions. This is what I have so far. If I break it up into separate programs I can make them all work. For example if I leave out my function and the conversion entirely it successfully displays all my input onto the screen as required. I need to convert those char values into char* to use them with my function or predefined string functions that I'm aware of. I'm unsure how to do this.

```
#include <iostream> // my libraries needed for files and strings
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void pigConfig(char*); // function used to convert input into Pig Latin

int main()
{
    char inputString[101]; // string declared to hold the anticipated values and null terminator
    char next;
    ifstream inStream;

    inStream.open("ASSGN8-A.txt"); //opening file and checking if open correctly
    if (inStream.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    inStream.get(next); //outputting the input to the screen
    while(!inStream.eof())
    {
        cout << next;
        inStream.get(next);
    }
    
    pigConfig(inputString); // calling on the function
    inStream.close();
    return 0;
}

void pigConfig(char *ptr)
{
    char first = ptr[0]; //initializing char to hold first letter of first word

    //use for loop to check all characters of
    //string to find a space or null terminator,
    //which mark the end of a word
    for(int index = 1; index <= strlen(ptr); index++)
    {
        if(ptr[index] == ' ')
        {
            cout << (char)toupper(first) << "AY" << " "; //pints first letter of current word together with AY and space
            first = ptr[index+1];
            index++;
        }
    else if(ptr[index] == '\0') //check for end of string to run a final time
    {
        cout << (char)toupper(first) << "AY";
        return;
    }
    else
    cout << (char)toupper(ptr[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char next;
...
strcpy(inputString,next);
```

The `strcpy` function copies a string. However, `next` is a `char`, not a string. So this call to `strcpy` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ya I was trying to experiment with the functions I do know. I will remove it as its an old line of code.